# Fourier transform proof

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to prove that
$$\langle\tilde{s}(\omega), \omega^{2}\tilde{s}(\omega)\rangle = -\langle s(t), \partial_t^2 s(t)\rangle$$

Where $\tilde{s}(\omega)$ is defined as the Fourier transform of a signal $s(t)$ such that
$$\tilde{s}\omega =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} s(t)e^{-i\omega t} \, dt$$

**My attempt at an answer:**

We already know that 
$$\mathcal{F}[\partial_t s(t)](\omega) = i\omega \mathcal{F}[s(t)](\omega)$$
and hence it follows that
$$\mathcal{F}[\partial_t^2 s(t)](\omega) = -\omega^2 \mathcal{F}[s(t)](\omega)$$

so

$$\langle \tilde{s}(\omega), \omega^2 \tilde{s}(\omega)\rangle = \langle\mathcal{F}[s(t)], -\mathcal{F}[\partial_t^2 s(t)]\rangle$$

At some point I'm going to have to red rid of the fourier transforms - but how do I go about doing that? Is it better to work in full integral notation and to switch to inner products at the end of the proof?

Comment: Please: write $\langle f,g\rangle$, not $<f,g>$.  (I edited the question accordingly.) ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

The [Plancherel theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem) may help you. It just says $\langle\tilde f,\tilde g \rangle = \langle f,g\rangle$.

Comment: Do you mean that $$<\mathcal{F}[s(t)], -\mathcal{F}[\partial_t^{2}s(t)]> = <s(t), -\partial_t^{2}s(t)>$$?

Comment: @william exactly.

Comment: so helpful. I knew parseval's theorem, but somehow didn't think to use it here. D'oh